# Inserting data into datatable based on row value

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Lets say you have a datatable with the following three columns:

```
ID,Size,Value
```

Is it possible to update the value column of a specific row based on the value of the `ID` of that row, pretty much to be able to run a SQL query of there is faster or better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to update the value column of a specific row based on
>   the value of the ID of that row

Yes, you can use [`DataRow.SetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353039%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and a little bit of Linq:

```
var rowsToUdate = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<int>("ID") == id);
foreach(DataRow row in rowsToUpDate)
    row.SetField("Value", newValue);
```

> ...pretty much to be able to run a SQL query of there is faster or
>   better way?

So do you want to update the database instead of the `DataTable`? This part is confusing.

Comment: Is it possible to be able to do the code you provided above, but select * on column ID and not need a where clause?

Comment: @user2593590: What do you mean with _"select * on column ID and not need a where "_?